# How to set lib path in ANT when the build file location changes

Tags: java, ant

I am new to Ant. Following is the folder structure for my application.

- src : source code
- lib : jars
- util : build.xml (ant build file)
- output : This will have a jar file generated from source

The user should be able to copy this jar file in the output folder to anywhere and when extracted it will have

- lib folder: contains all the libs needed
- build.xml : ant build file to run

The user should be able to run this build.xml as
     "ant -f build.xml run"

The problem is, in the code structure the build.xml is under output folder, so when I write the build.xml, the lib folder path is set to ../lib/
But when the build.xml is run from the extracted folder, the build.xml is at root level and ../lib will not work since the relative path for lib would be "./lib/"

Help appreciated!

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make lib dir dynamic, loaded from a property file. In the properties file `local.props` (that will be packaged into the jar in the root) you will have:

```
lib.dir=lib
```

You will have also another `local.props` file for your build process, when `build.xml` is in `util` directory. This file would have:

```
lib.dir=../lib
```

One of the first instructions in your build file must be:

```
<property file="local.props" />
```

When referencing to lib directory always use `${lib.dir}`. This will make lib directory not only flexible, but also configurable on user side, as a side effect. `local.props` file is commonly used to provide configurability to script user.

Comment: One quick question.. Can I generate this local.props (bundled in jar) with lib.dir=lib and have another local.props with lib.dir=../lib? Since this is going to be a fixed folder structure, the user might not want to set this manually.. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Try putting the build.xml outside the util folder..or add util/ to output list output.library.jar = bin/,\util/ in build.properties file

Comment: I can not really move the build.xml out of util folder. I did not understand the last part. What am I supposed to add to build.properties file exactly?